# Fire event when "delete" key from keyboard is pressed

Tags: asp.net

I have a `gridview` from which I am marking grades and entering them to database. What I want is that whenever the user presses the `delete` button from keyboard I want to do something like deleting some record from database which I can manage as I know which `gridview` cell will be selected. Basically I want to trap if `delete` key is pressed and then do something with that.

I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You need to search javascript code that first capture the keyboard of the page, then use that to make post back... what you ask here not shown any try to to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET each WebControl has a so called Accesskey-Property, which bind the Control to a Keyboard click + ALT.
So what you have to to is make a button with the functionality to delete the selected row, and map it to the backspace or delete key.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.accesskey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Now you want to get rid of the the ALT? You will have to use jQuery to map the click of Delete also the Button.

```
$( "#yourgrid" ).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 46) {
        $("#yourbutton").click();
    }
});
```